# One-sided alternative hypothesis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am a little bit confused about definitions of null and alternative hypotheses.

My understanding is that the null and alternative hypotheses are defined based one a partition of the parameter space $\Theta$. Suppose that $\Theta$ can be partitioned into two disjoint subsets $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta_1$. Then, the null is such that $\theta \in \Theta_0$ and the alternative is such that $\theta \in \Theta_1$.

However, it is not uncommon to find examples where people test:
$$ H_0: \theta = \theta_0 \quad\text{versus}\quad H_1: \theta > \theta_0 $$
or
$$ H_0: \theta = \theta_0 \quad\text{versus}\quad H_1: \theta < \theta_0 .$$
For example, here :

- [https://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/courses/200/lec07.pdf](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eowen/courses/200/lec07.pdf) (bottom of page 3)
- http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/sigtest.htm

These hypotheses don't form a partition of the parameter space (assuming $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$). Is it still correct to do that? Do people assume (implicitly) that the equality in the null is actually an inequality?

Comment: You do not have to partition the parameter space.  Indeed a simple hypothesis test is $H_0:\theta =\theta_0$ versus $H_1:\theta =\theta_1$.  Even using a parametric family of distributions excludes other possibilities from the analysis.

Comment: I like to think of the alternative hypothesis as pointing towards what counts as "more extreme" when looking at the probability of the observation or a more extreme outcome under the null hypothesis

Comment: For practical purposes, $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ vs $H_a: \mu > \mu_0.$ is the same as $H_0: \mu \le \mu_0$ vs $H_a: \mu > \mu_0.$ In either case, the distribution under $H_0$ uses parameter $\mu_0.$

Comment: @Henry. Thanks. Maybe another way to look at it would be to say that we restricted our statistical model to the parameter space $\Theta = \{ \theta_0, \theta_1\}$. Because essentially, any other value of the parameter are not considered when testing simple hypotheses. And this extends to other cases such as $H_0:\theta = \theta_0$ and $H_1:\theta>\theta_0$. What do you think?

Comment: @BruceET. Thanks. I understand that the tests you mentioned could be equivalent in some situations. But I am wondering if this is true in general... You need some kind of monotonicity property of the power function to claim that. Right?

Comment: Yo got to be careful with what you read. Your first reference from Standford says in the third paragraph of page 4 "If we don’t reject H0 then we accept H0.". That should be enough evidence to quickly walk away.

For your second reference, the parameter space is not defined, so we can't really say if it is being partitioned.

Comment: Take a look at examples 3 and 4 in this lecture: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture16.pdf

I think that the way you build you alternative hypothesis allows you to gain more statistical power to reject the null hypothesis with the same amount of data. Of course, with a one-sided alternative hypothesis, you are making a strong assumption about the true parameter not being in the other side not covered by it. If the true parameter is actually in that other side, your test is meaningless.

This discussion is also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19012/90512

Comment: On a second thought, that strong assumption about the true parameter not being on the other side not covered by the alternative hypothesis effectively means that we have reduced (redefined?) our parameter space, and that the model is misspecified if the true parameter is indeed on that side...something that is suggested in the answer linked in my previous comment...

Answer (score 0):

> . You need some kind of monotonicity property of the power function to claim that. Right?

Yes, correct.

Remember that the I type error (test size) is defined as

$$\alpha=\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0}\pi(\theta)$$

Here is a formal definition of UMP Test

[image]

this explains why $\mathcal{H}_0:\mu\leq\mu_0 \equiv \mathcal{H}_0:\mu=\mu_0$

---

Actually there are many hypothesis-testing problems for which a UMP test does not exist. In these situation usually the tests are restricted in a class of Unbiased ones. **If a test is biased** it cannot be used because it might give incoherent results

a test $\gamma$ is unbiased iff

$$\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0}\pi_{\gamma}(\theta)\leq \inf_{\theta \in \Theta_1}\pi_{\gamma}(\theta)$$